# Process communication with message queue

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I have a problem with a communication queue. In my server program, which I'm trying to write, I need to communicate between two processes created with the fork function.
I am receiving an  `Invalid Argument` error but I don't know why.  Here is my simplified non-working) code.

```
key_t key = ftok(".",'A');
msgget(key,IPC_CREAT);
perror(""); //receive succes

if(fork()>0){
    msgbuf dat;

    msgrcv(key,(void*)&dat,(size_t)sizeof(dat),500,0);
    perror(""); //receive INVALID ARGUMENT
    cout<<dat.mtext<<endl;
}
else
{
    msgbuf data;
    data.mtext[0]='a';
    data.mtype=500;

    msgsnd(key,(void*)&data,(size_t)sizeof(data),0);
    perror(""); //receive INVALID ARGUMENT
}
```

What shall I correct to make it work?

P.S I've even tried to use a sleep function to wait for the child process but it doesn't help.

Comment: Did not do low level programming like this for long, but from the manual page, sizeof(dat) is wrong. It rather needs to be the size of the mtext field within msgbuf.

Comment: Don't call `perror()` unless you know that the return value from `msgrcv()` was `-1`. `errno` may contain a bogus value, or one related to a function called 3 days ago if `msgrcv()` doesn't indicate that it failed. If `msrgrcv()` did fail, then `EINVAL` (or "Invalid Argument") indicates that "`msgid` was invalid, or `msgsz` was less than 0", according to my manual page for it...

Answer (score 1):

`msgrcv/msgsnd` takes an integer msqid returned from `msgget` *not* the key.

```
int qid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT);

msgrcv(qid, (void*)&data, (size_t) sizeof(data), 500, 0);

//..........

msgsnd(qid,(void*) &dat,(size_t) sizeof(dat), 0);
```

Remember that the `data` struct should include a `long` msgtype as the first field that you set, in this case presumably of msgtype = 500 since that is what you are trying to read.